# Could a node can be stoped by another node?

Tags: ros, opencv2, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys !
I want to stop a node, once its published message is subscribe by another node.
For example

Node 1(publisher)

```
def bridge_opencv():
        image_pub = rospy.Publisher("quadrotor/videocamera1/camera_info",Image)

            cv2.namedWindow("Image window", 1)
        
        image_sub = rospy.Subscriber("quadrotor/videocamera1/image",Image, callback)
        
            
def callback(data):
        
        bridge = CvBridge()
        try:
            cv_image = bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(data, "bgr8")
        except CvBridgeError, e:
            print e
        (rows,cols,channels) = cv_image.shape
        if cols > 60 and rows > 60 :
            cv2.circle(cv_image, (50,50), 10, 255)
                        x=5
                        puba.publish(x)                
        cv2.imshow("Image window", cv_image)
        cv2.waitKey(3)
def pilot():
       puba = rospy.Publisher("box_positiona", Float64)   
       bridge_opencv()
       rospy.spin()
if __name__ == '__main__':
        pilot()
```

Node 2 :(subscriber)

```
def where1(msg):
    global x1
    x1 = msg.data
    print x1

def ground():
    global cmd
    
    rospy.init_node("ground")   
        
    rospy.Subscriber("/box_positiona", Float64, where1)
        >>once i subscribe to that topic,stop node 1 immediatley
if __name__ == '__main__':
        ground()
```

Thanks a lot !
Looking forward for your answers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/174714/could-a-node-can-be-stoped-by-another-node-?/) by [jashanvir](https://answers.ros.org/users/14866/jashanvir/) on ROS Answers with karma: 68 on 2014-06-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you sure you want to stop once subscribed? You do NOT have a message then.

This whole thing also goes against usual ROS usage patterns. For one time things a service call might be better suited. It might be a good idea to state what you want to actually achieve with this.

If you want to stop a node there are some possibilities.

- Nodes are binaries, you can just kill them with a normal system command (you'll need to know the pid/name or figure it out)
- `rosnode kill <node>` kills the node with name `<node>`.
- If you don't know the node's name for the setup, but have some kind of ROS configurable connection you can send a shutdown service/message that would trigger that node to end itself manually.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0